# Lazy loading data in table with global filter using Angular + PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, primeng-datatable, global-filter

I have created a datatable with both *Lazy loading* and *global filter* features.
I used PrimeNG components for the implementation.
But I found that the global filter is not working when lazy loading is enabled, i.e. [lazy]="true".

**HTML Code :**

```
<input #gc type="text" pInputText size="30" placeholder="Global Filter" class="element-space">

<p-dataTable [value]="infoList" [rows]="5" [globalFilter]="gc" [totalRecords]="records" (onLazyLoad)="loadInfo($event)"
  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" virtualScroll="virtualScroll" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedInfo"
  (onRowSelect)="onInfoRowSelect($event)" dataKey="infoId" class="break-word" resizableColumns="true" [lazy]="true">
```

**TS code :**

```
    lazyLoadOutInfo(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.infoListData) {
            this.infoList= this.infoListData.slice(event.first, (event.first + event.rows));
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

I need to have both features working, does anybody have a clue here ?

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here for reference, as this question is old.

It seems this is on purpose, from my understanding reading through this thread:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1342